# Create App for standalone Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning, app

I've created a Visualforce page which is not linked to any specific object, but has the option to read in a csv file and upload data to whichever object is selected from a dropdown picklist.

I would like to create an App to display this page (for use when creating a new sandbox), but am confused as to how to achieve this. All I have currently are the VF page and its controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a custom visualforce tab associated to your page and a custom app that has only that tab.

Comment: Great yes of course -:)